# PHP web crawler - undefined index

Tags: php, web-crawler, wamp

I am following along a tutorial for a PHP web crawler and I keep getting an error concerning my indexing.  [PHP tutorial](https://subinsb.com/how-to-create-a-simple-web-crawler-in-php)

```
ERROR: 
Notice: Undefined index: path in C:\wamp\www\crawler.php on line 19 
Call Stack
# Time   Memory  Function   Location
1 0.0010 260216  {main}( )  ..\crawler.php:0
2 0.0080 730552  crawl_site( )  ..\crawler.php:47
3 1.8320 2344408 perfect_url( ) ..\crawler.php:38
```

This is the function that is giving the error:

```
function rel2abs($rel, $base){
 if (parse_url($rel, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != ''){
  return $rel;
 }
 if ($rel[0]=='#' || $rel[0]=='?'){
  return $base.$rel;
 }
 extract(parse_url($base));
 $path = preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', '', $path);
 if ($rel[0] == '/'){
  $path = '';
 }
 $abs = "$host$path/$rel";
 $re = array('#(/.?/)#', '#/(?!..)[^/]+/../#');
 for($n=1; $n>0;$abs=preg_replace($re,'/', $abs,-1,$n)){}
 $abs=str_replace("../","",$abs);
 return $scheme.'://'.$abs;
}
```

Line 19: `$re = array('#(/.?/)#', '#/(?!..)[^/]+/../#');`

Comment: probably a variable scope, by the looks of it, it's not even making its way there

Comment: It always amazes me how people can work with such messy code... Aside from that, post your full code with the line where the error occurs. The line you posted as 19, should not be causing the error.

Comment: your `Line 19: $re = array('#(/.?/)#', '#/(?!..)[^/]+/../#');` does not have a `index: path` in it, so that is not line #19.

Comment: It isn't line 19 causing your error. You're doing this: `extract(parse_url($base));` which leads you to assume that `$path` gets extracted from `$base`. Yeah, **no**... do a simple `print_r($base);` and you'll see.

Comment: looking at your linked tutorial, it is probably caused by this line `if(($bp['path']!="/" && $bp['path']!="") || $bp['path']==''){` in `function perfect_url($u,$b){`

Comment: I am sorry, line 19 is: `$abs = "$host$path/$rel";`

Comment: `$host` isn't even defined, in turn failing all other variables following it.

Comment: problem is that even with line #19 being `$abs = "$host$path/$rel";` you would be getting `Notice: Undefined variable: path` not `Notice: Undefined index: path`

Comment: I don't know if I should vote to close as unclear, or as undefined index. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: @Fred-ii- it looks like `$host`/`$path`/etc. are created/defined by `extract(parse_url($base));` ([`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)). I just learned something as well.

Comment: @Sean thanks Sean. Yet as you said above, the notice doesn't seem to support the code.

Comment: @Darren, although wouldn't that result in a `Notice: Undefined variable: path` not `Notice: Undefined index: path` when `$path` is called? since the OP never does `$base['path']` which would give the `Notice: Undefined index: path`?